# Error with array bounds

Tags: android, io, android-intent

I have been Googling and toying around with different methods and I am still unsuccessful.

Essentially what I am doing is passing a resource id within an intent to a new activity. The I extract the int from the intent and I attempt to instantiate an object using the context and resource id which I unpacked from the intent.

First activity which packs the intent and starts the next activity:

```
case R.id.KoreanVocabularymenuBButton:          
Intent openBeginnerVocabularyActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), KoreanVocabularyActivity.class); 
openBeginnerVocabularyActivity.putExtra("difficulty", R.raw.beginner_numbers);
startActivity(openBeginnerVocabularyActivity);
break;
```

The second activity unpacks the intent and attempts to instantiate an object with the data:

```
int resource = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("difficulty");
korean = new KoreanVocabulary(this, resource);
```

This is the constructor of the object and where the error appears to occur:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String word = null;

    try {
        while ((word = br.readLine()) != null){
            vocabulary[index++] = word;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

edit:

index is an integer. The vocabulary[] array is a private member of the function. The constructor is attempting to initialize the array.

I tried to use logcat and got a bit of a mess:

```
I/ActivityManager(   51): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000     cmp=korean.koreanstudy/.MainMenuActivity bnds=[5,234][115,352] }
W/WindowManager(   51): No window to dispatch pointer action 0
W/WindowManager(   51): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
I/ActivityManager(   51): Displayed activity korean.koreanstudy/.MainMenuActivity: 388 ms (total 388 ms)
I/ActivityManager(   51): Starting activity: Intent {   cmp=korean.koreanstudy/.VocabularyMenuActivity }
I/ActivityManager(   51): Displayed activity korean.koreanstudy/.VocabularyMenuActivity: 322 ms (total 322 ms)
I/ActivityManager(   51): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=korean.koreanstudy/.KoreanVocabularyActivity (has extras) }
I/global  (  250): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
D/AndroidRuntime(  250): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  250): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
E/AndroidRuntime(  250): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(  250): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{korean.koreanstudy/korean.koreanstudy.KoreanVocabularyActivity}:      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

The reason I want the ID of the resource is because I want to initialize the object with a specific file resource. I need a way to identify the specific file. The way I have been trying is within a switch case on a menu. The user clicks the difficulty level and the specific list will be loaded for that difficulty in the next activity. However, I need to know which difficulty the user selected. That is why I am trying to keep track of the ID.

edit 2:

This is the class and constructor info for the array.

```
private int index = 0; 
private int max = 0;
private String[] vocabulary = new String[255];

public KoreanVocabulary(Context context, int resource){
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(resource);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String word = null;

    try {
        while ((word = br.readLine()) != null){
            vocabulary[index++] = word;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    max = index;
    index = 0;
    }
```

edit 3:

Sorry everyone, I found the problem. I somehow had an off by one reference when reading from the array. I thought the problem was with the file reading but as you have all pointed out that was fine-- you are right! sorry!

Comment: What error occurs? Add the LogCat output to your post. Also, why are you passing the Recource-ID from the Intent? You can access recourses everywhere you have a `Context`-Object.

Comment: You should remove the solution from the question and describe it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the resource you just need to get the context (your Activity will already have this) and call it normally. You shouldn't be passing the resource.

Also, you aren't exactly passing the resource per say... you are passing the value of that resource thus it is just better to access that from your next activity

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

String word = null;

try {
    while ((word = br.readLine()) != null){
        vocabulary[index++] = word; //<!-- POI#1
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //<!-- POI#2
}
```

Point of interest #1: Where is `vocabulary`/`index` coming from? What datatypes are they? `index` is probably `int`, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Point of interest #2: Are you getting an exception? If so, is it the `IOException`? It not, what's the actual error you're getting? I think you forgot that part in your original post - `logcat` should be able to give you the information you need.

Comment: I updated the initial post and tried to address those points.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a connection between the constructor

```
korean = new KoreanVocabulary(this, resource);
```

and the rest of your code, but couldn't find any. The error you are getting, i guess, is an IOException... where is

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

getting its input from?
I do believe the title of the question is somewhat wrong - you do pass resources between the two activities. This is not the problem in the code (unless the logcat will show something different, of course). **edit - not to mention that, as others stated already, the R.* resources are available all over, no need to pass them between activities...

Comment: Can you show how you initialize the array? As i said, this has nothing to do with passing the resources, this you do fine. Somewhere in the constructor you use either an uninitialized array, or an array smaller than what you request. The error probably referrers to the vocabulary[] array.

Comment: I updated the info-- I have shown the entire constructor and data it uses.

Comment: The Raw resource is an array of strings? How large is this array?

Comment: I figured it out-- it was loading one too many. A silly novice mistake. Sorry!